# usb video capture device: video displayed OK but NO sound?

Tags: sound, usb, video, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to digitize my old Video8 videos with a Terratec GrabsterAV350MX usb device on a Kubuntu system. Video display, and capture on basis of v4l2 is no problem.

However I cannot get any sound. "Playing" around with PulseAudio all of a sudden I surpringly got a reaction on one of the volume meters and succeeded to record the video sound with the following code:

```
avconv -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48000 -f pulse -i alsa_input.usb-0ccd_Grabster_AV_350-01-G350.analog-stereo -acodec libvorbis -aq 6 test.ogg
```

So, in principle it works. The unfortunate thing is that I cannot repeat this anymore, and being new to consciously using PuleAudio I am afraid the notes I took while experimenting are not complete.

Can anyone advise which settings I have to do that I can playback/record from this usb capture device?

Here the typical dumps:

```
~$ aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Gerät 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Gerät 3: VT1708S Digital [VT1708S Digital]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0

~$ arecord -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (CAPTURE) ****
Karte 0: Intel [HDA Intel], Gerät 0: VT1708S Analog [VT1708S Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 1: G350 [Grabster AV 350], Gerät 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0

~$ pactl list short sinks | cut -f2
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer

~$ pactl list short sources | cut -f2
alsa_input.usb-0ccd_Grabster_AV_350-01-G350.analog-stereo
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer.monitor

~$ pactl list sinks
Sink #0
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
        Beschreibung: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzermodul: 6
        Stumm: no
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
        Verteilung 0,00
        Basislautstärke: 100%
                     0,00 dB
        Quellenüberwachung: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Merkmale: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "VT1708S Analog"
                alsa.id = "VT1708S Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf9ff8000 irq 45"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "3a3e"
                device.product.name = "82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "VIA VT1708S"
                alsa.components = "HDA:11060397,10438346,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Profile:
                analog-output: Analoge Ausgabe (priority: 9900)
                analog-output-headphones: Analoge Kopfhörer (priority: 9000, not available)
        Aktive Profile: analog-output
        Formate:
                pcm

Sink #1
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer
        Beschreibung: FFT based equalizer on Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-equalizer-sink.c
        Sample-Angabe: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzermodul: 22
        Stumm: no
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
        Verteilung 0,00
        Basislautstärke: 100%
        Quellenüberwachung: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer.monitor
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Merkmale: HW_MUTE_CTRL LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                device.description = "FFT based equalizer on Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
                device.master_device = "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
                device.class = "filter"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Formate:
                pcm

~$ pactl list sources
Quelle #0
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_input.usb-0ccd_Grabster_AV_350-01-G350.analog-stereo
        Beschreibung: Grabster AV 350 Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 5
        Stumm: no
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke:  54%
                     -16,00 dB
        Sink-Monitor: k. A.
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "USB Audio"
                alsa.id = "USB Audio"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "1"
                alsa.card_name = "Grabster AV 350"
                alsa.long_card_name = "Grabster AV 350 at usb-0000:00:1a.7-6, high speed"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:6:1.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.1/sound/card1"
                udev.id = "usb-0ccd_Grabster_AV_350-01-G350"
                device.bus = "usb"
                device.vendor.id = "0ccd"
                device.vendor.name = "TerraTec Electronic GmbH"
                device.product.id = "0084"
                device.product.name = "Grabster AV 350"
                device.serial = "0ccd_Grabster_AV_350"
                device.string = "front:1"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Grabster AV 350 Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
                alsa.components = "USB0ccd:0084"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
        Profile:
                analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100)
        Aktive Profile: analog-input-linein
        Formate:
                pcm

Quelle #1
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
        Beschreibung: Monitor of Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 6
        Stumm: no
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke: 100%
                     0,00 dB
        Sink-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                device.description = "Monitor of Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
                device.class = "monitor"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf9ff8000 irq 45"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "3a3e"
                device.product.name = "82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "0"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Formate:
                pcm

Quelle #2
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
        Beschreibung: Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample-Angabe: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 6
        Stumm: yes
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke:  10%
                     -60,75 dB
        Sink-Monitor: k. A.
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = "VT1708S Analog"
                alsa.id = "VT1708S Analog"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel at 0xf9ff8000 irq 45"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "8086"
                device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
                device.product.id = "3a3e"
                device.product.name = "82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller"
                device.form_factor = "internal"
                device.string = "front:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
                alsa.mixer_name = "VIA VT1708S"
                alsa.components = "HDA:11060397,10438346,00100000"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Profile:
                analog-input-microphone-front: Mikrofon vorne (priority: 8500, not available)
                analog-input-microphone-rear: Mikrofon hinten (priority: 8200, available)
                analog-input-linein: Line In (priority: 8100, not available)
        Aktive Profile: analog-input-microphone-rear
        Formate:
                pcm

Quelle #3
        Status: SUSPENDED
        Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer.monitor
        Beschreibung: Monitor of FFT based equalizer on Internes Audio Analog Stereo
        Treiber: module-equalizer-sink.c
        Sample-Angabe: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
        Kanalzuordnung: front-left,front-right
        Besitzer-Modul: 22
        Stumm: no
        Lautstärke: 0: 100% 1: 100%
                0: 0,00 dB 1: 0,00 dB
                Verteilung 0,00
        Basis-Lautstärke: 100%
                     0,00 dB
        Sink-Monitor: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.equalizer
        Latenz: 0 usec, eingestellt 0 usec
        Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Eigenschaften:
                device.description = "Monitor of FFT based equalizer on Internes Audio Analog Stereo"
                device.class = "monitor"
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        Formate:
                pcm
```

speaker-test -t wav -c2 works allright.

There is one information, though, which I wonder whether or not it has any relevance, namely for the source #0 alsa_input.usb-0ccd_Grabster_AV_350-01-G350.analog-stereo there is no sink-monitor listed!?

I don't know anymore which screw to turn. I do hope someone in the forum has some systematic advise for me.

Answer (score 1):

OK, modprobe setting was wrong. For all of you who will encounter the same problem see here:

[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...ux/+bug/998143][1]

The workaround is Grabby (while I turned crabby in the process of trying to find a solution):

```
sudo rmmod em28xx
sudo modprobe em28xx card=67
```

instead of what would be the correct card

```
sudo rmmod em28xx
```

sudo modprobe em28xx card=68